# One-liner $in nullification MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The idea is to make a request (in JS) that fetch documents with a field being contained in a given array if the array is defined, or all documents if the array is not defined.

I just wondered if there is any elegant mean to give the $in argument a parameter that nullifies its behavior, that can be used as an one-liner. I take any idea you have to make this kind of conditional request more elegant.

Here is a snippet using Mongoose:

```
let query = SomeModel.find();
if (someArray) {
    query = query.where(someField).in(someArray);
}
query.exec();
```

Sure it works, but it requires to store the query in a variable, so not so cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation might help.

```
let itemValues = someArray || [];
SomeModel.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "someField": {
            [itemValues.length > 0 ? "$in" : "$nin"]: itemValues}
        }
}
]).exec()
```

Comment: Fine! I'll try to see if there is any performance loss with the using of $nin.

Comment: I'd love to know results of your benchmark testing.